# What's the logic behind WCF generated names for DataContracts

Tags: wcf, soap

When I use WCF to expose a DataContract as a SOAP wevservice I get some funky genenerated names, such as:

```
[Flags]
public enum EnumType1
{
    EnumMember1 = 1;
    EnumMember2 = 2;
    EnumMember3 = 4;
}

[DataMember]
private Dictionary< EnumType1, Class1>  Class1Dictionary;
```

Has this soap representation over the wire: (I'm paraphrasing):

```
<Class1Dictionary>
    <KeyValueOfEnumType1Class1UTLV0zE5>
        <Key>EnumMember1 </Key>
        <Value> ... </Value>
    </KeyValueOfEnumType1Class1UTLV0zE5>
</Class1Dictionary>
```

What's the logic behind KeyValueOfEnumType1Class1UTLV0zE5? I can explain the KeyValueOfEnumType1Class1 part, but where does UTLV0zE5 come from? Furthermore will a WCF client break if this arbitrary string charges?

Answer (score 0):

It does look a bit random to me. I don't know whether the funk is random and subject to changes that will break contracts.

But if you are in search of less funcky WSDL, a workaround (from [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/1126490d-5a9f-4285-a86e-d7c657e6786f)) is to subclass the dictionary and use the [CollectionDataContractAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.collectiondatacontractattribute.aspx) to override the output during serialization:

```
[CollectionDataContract(
    Name="MyDictionary", ItemName="Items", KeyName="Key", ValueName="Value")]
public class MyDictionary: Dictionary<EnumType1, Class1>
{        
}
```

Should generate xml like:

```
<MyDictionary> 
    <Items> 
        <Key>EnumMember1</Key> 
        <Value> ... </Value> 
    </Items> 
</MyDictionary>
```

Comment: Good point, but it still does not answer the question of how those are generated in the first place, and wether WCF requires them specifically for service compatibility.

Comment: @David Reis - I would be interested to know how they are generated also - they do look pretty random. I can't really imagine why they are there for compatibility reasons. It would seem more likely to me that the WSDL types need to be unique, and using the default names leads to a higher likelihood of collisions - so it appends some base64-encoded characters to reduce the likelihood. Obviously changing them would break the service contract between a client and the service, so I doubt they are random each time. Maybe it's a hash of the service name or something like that.

Comment: It turns out that whatever is the method, it doesn't matter, because the DataContracts are consider compatible whatever those generated strings are.